# Problems authenticating using JSForce

Tags: javascript, oauth2, jsforce

so I've been trying to use JSForce to authenticate into SF. I used both the first example with SOAP API login and the second one with OAuth2: https://jsforce.github.io/document/#connection

However, I keep getting the same error each time:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Any help? The account credentials used to authorize are a system admin, so permissions shouldn't be an issue, and I have the redirect URI as 
`redirectUri : 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize'`

Comment: I guess that is due to same origin policy of browsers. You will require a proxy as documented. You cannot make GET/ POST calls from JavaScript to another domain. https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce-ajax-proxy/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Are there any ways to authenticate that doesn't require this proxy? I'm using a cloud-based host service so I can't install anything like this link requires. How do people normally authenticate external apps to SF?

Comment: [Setup > Security Controls > CORS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/extend_code_cors.htm) will allow you to safely allow your site access using JSForce.

Comment: I believe that will not work on login.salesforce.com because the request will go to an authentication server, however you may give it a try.

Comment: @manjit_singh - login.salesforce.com does not enforce same origin policy (AFAIK), it only enforces no iframe which is why lightning broke it.....

Comment: Just curious, so does it sends `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *` header with response? I believe it's a browser enforcement not to allow cross domain request unless cors is allowed or server sends Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Comment: I tried whitelist https://*.visual.force.com still getting access denied, when I try to access another instance of salesforce using username password flow.

Comment: @AKor I have used OAuth user agent flow and it works fine if you want to issue requests using JavaScript